# Django writes to DB before each GET http request.

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am using django via scalearc for the database, ScaleArc establishes connection to respective database depending on read/write Query.
When I do GET call django is sending following query to database due to that its always connecting to Write database.

```
SET NAMES utf8  
set autocommit=0  
set autocommit=1  
SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL = 0
```

How do I avoid these calls in Django?

Comment: django is not writing, but configuring the connection.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this ? I would like to test and check.

Comment: Check your DATABASES configuration in your settings file.  There are usually connection settings set there.